# How to execute a javascript function without modifying existing html files?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, .htaccess

I have run into a situation where my company has decided to archive/move all the old html files into a new domain say **archive.company.com.** Now what I would like to be able to do is for every request to the archive domain, after the content is loaded, there will be a popup saying that this content is old. Since there are thousands of html files, I do not want to touch them. Is there any way to run a piece of javascript code from htaccess or any other means ?

Comment: You could create a wrapper page that includes the archived pages in an iframe, and create the popup in that wrapper page. As far as I know there's no way to include javascript in a file without editing that file or any of the already referenced scripts etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use a single css in all of your html files you can use [`:before` and `:after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) to insert content.

e.g.:

```
h1::before {
    content: "This content is old!";
}
```

Another idea would be to add a cgi handler to html files on that subdomain. Then create your own html-cgi-"interpreter", that just outputs the original html with some additional javascript.

Sample Apache configuration snipplet:

```
AddHandler application/x-old-html html
Action application/x-old-html /path/to/the/script
```

The sample script may simply use awk or sed to replace `<body>` with `<body><script language="JavaScript">alert("Old content");</script>`.

Comment: Hi, after some googling, I preferred using Apache configuration to handle this issue. But I am very new to perl or Apache. Could you please point me to the right direction to implement your method of adding Handler and Action to Apache's configuration ?